# Получить значение из базы

Tags: php

Работаю с библиотекой medoo. Подскажите, как получить значение price, где itemId = $itemId  ?

```
 $db_site = $this->Connect(self::$_conf['icon_db']);
 $price = $db_site->get("shop", "price", "itemId" => $itemId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$db_site->get("shop", "price", [
    "itemId" => $itemId
]);
```

В medoo, нужно передать массив с условиями

Comment: так я уже пробовала, выдает ошибку - syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: @Елизавета какая версия php? может нужно array("itemId" => $itemId) вместо [..]

Comment: array("itemId" => $itemId)   в этом случае возвращает "Array"

Comment: @Елизавета это результат функции get? get должна вернуть строку, если её второй параметр строка

Comment: $price = $db_site->select("shop", "price", array("itemId" => $itemId));   -  $itemId = $_GET['itemId'];  (любое число)

Answer (score 0):

решила так:

```
$price = $db_site->select('shop','*' ,array('itemId'=>$itemId));
if($price !== false and count($price) > 0 and $price[0]['price'] != ''){
   echo $price[0]['price'];
}
```